# How use Transaction with more than functions using c#

Tags: c#, transactions

How use Transaction with more than functions using c#
for example
i have three function

```
//first function 
save();//------to save data-----
//second function 
saveDetailes(); //-----to save detiales ----------
//third function 
updateStauts(); //--------to update onother table ---------------
```

I want to ensure that all of them are implemented or not implemented using TransAction
thanks

Comment: We are going to need more details here....

Comment: Whats detiales are you need

Comment: quetion how to use transacton with three functions and immpemntation it togther

Comment: It appears that these ,methods saves some data into a database. We need to know if you are using ado.net, EF, or some other ORM. We need to know if these methods use stored procedures or inline sql (and in fact, if this is actually a relational database or a NoSql database) - All you've given us is just how you call these methods - that's not enough to even start describing the problem, let alone solve it.

Comment: using ado.net and using sqlinside visual stideo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after alot of tries and search alot of resorces i was found a solution for my problem

**solution by** 
passing a sqlcommand to all functions and return from every fuction as aboolean value is save done return true 
if three function return true 
transaction be commit other ways transaction roolback 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correctly you need to use a common SqlTransaction in multiple methods. This is how I do it. First you have to gather all of your methods into a common one. Then you pass your one SqlConenction and SqlTransaction to all of your methods and return a boolean flag to notify your main method whether your queries were sucessfully or not.

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SqlTransationDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Do your sql logic here 
            DoSomething();
        }

        private static bool DoSomething()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection("SqlConnectionString"))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    //If not commited, transaction is rolled-back as soon as it is disposed 
                    using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        //Either use a false loop to break or throw an exception. Your choice. 
                        do
                        {
                            if (!Foo1(connection, transaction))
                                break;
                            if (!Foo2(connection, transaction))
                                break;
                            if (!Foo3(connection, transaction))
                                break;

                            //Commit 
                            transaction.Commit();

                            return true;
                        }
                        while (false);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private static bool Foo1(SqlConnection Connection, SqlTransaction Transaction)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = Connection;
                    command.Transaction = Transaction;
                    command.CommandText = "Query1";
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private static bool Foo2(SqlConnection Connection, SqlTransaction Transaction)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = Connection;
                    command.Transaction = Transaction;
                    command.CommandText = "Query2";
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private static bool Foo3(SqlConnection Connection, SqlTransaction Transaction)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = Connection;
                    command.Transaction = Transaction;
                    command.CommandText = "Query3";
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```